# Read/write bot user data in Bot Framework when the `session` object is not available

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework

I want to store a simple key-value pair inside the bot's user data storage provided by Microsoft's Bot Framework.

Normally it's easy to do:

```
session.userData.key = value;
```

However, I want to do it when the `session` object is not available, in an event handler that processes all incoming messages:

```
bot.on('incoming', incoming => {
  // Check whether user asked to switch on debug mode.
  if (incoming.text === 'debug on') {
    console.log('Enabling debug mode.');
    // TODO FIXME - we need to save the result to bot memory.
  }
});
```

Is there any other way to save to bot memory from the main app.js file or from the event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, which is to use `UniversalBot.loadSession()`:

```
bot.on('incoming', incoming => {
  // Load the user session so that we can save values to userData.
  bot.loadSession(incoming.address, (error, session) => {
    if (!error) {
      // work with the session object as usual
    }
  });
});
```

After you load the `session` object, you can use `session.send()` and `session.userData` as usual.